# Why does my script parameter get deselected when being run?

Tags: unity-game-engine

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOcyl.jpg

Why is my point light script parameter being deactivated when I run unity..??

Comment: show the code in that script

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Nq4Y6

Comment: Don't post code as image or link to one .. copy it as text into your question instead. Don't post a link to an image but rather post the image within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line:

```
GetComponent<Light>();
```

You are setting it in the inspector, so no need to set it in the Start() method (also the Light is in the child object).
Delete that line and you're set.

(next time post the code in text not image.

Comment: If it wasn't in the child there would be no problem to use `GetComponent<xyz>()` within `Start()`. The OP also simply could have changed it to `GetComponentInChild<Light>()`